# I have embedded a video and I need to add a subtitle srt file to the HTML code

Tags: html, video-streaming, jwplayer

```
<html>
<div id="player2">
<div id="div2" style="display: block;">
<div class="movieplay">
<iframe src="http://www.somovie.co/harry-potter-and-the-goblet-of-fire-2005.html" height="100%" width="100%" 

webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

I need to add a srt file to the code and make it run with it.

Comment: srt is not natively supported right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

srt files do not work as subtitles right now. You can however use vtt files.
Convert srt files here: https://atelier.u-sub.net/srt2vtt/

```
<video controls preload="metadata">
   <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="file.vtt" default>
</video>
```

Comment: Text track from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.